# How do I install patches?

Tags: scripting, installation

I found a hairdynamicscollition.txt patch for Blender that I wish to install.

How do I do it?

I tried to run it as a script, but when I do so in the text editor in Blender, a red mark is over the first sentence text in the script text, and the script doesn't work.

Comment: You would use a patch if you are building blender from source.  https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Tools/Patches  Have a look at http://graphicall.org there may be a patched build to download there.

Comment: As mentioned, just to be clear  patches are not meant to be used directly by final users, they are to be applied to the source code directly by developers or advanced users before compiling blender for a certain platform.

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer is that you don't.

These patches are not intended for the end-user. They are intended to be used by developers to modify the source-code of Blender.

If you feel that you've got the skill-set to modify the source-code, more power to you! Unfortunately, most of us won't be much help. You'll get better support from the developers over at the [Blender development project](https://developer.blender.org/).

Comment: That is not totally correct, patches can be applied by any user able to [build Blender from source code](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender). This is no trivial task, but many users already do - and it gives you the power to control what you build, to do early tests on developments, etc.

Comment: Open-source projects certainly muddy the definition of "end-user," but I'd hardly call anyone who is building Blender from source an "end-user," generally. Even in a production environment, you'd never have an artist building from source. That's a Software Engineer's job.

Comment: lol, yeah, not in production for sure - but we do have some artists that build blender, and they are very precious for us (testing all changes very quickly, testing new features in development branches, etc.). It’s also a nice way for them to have more influence on blender's development. ;)

Comment: HAHAHA!!! True, **any** artist who can build from source is a precious resource, to be cherished anywhere, especially here ;-)